# Jobs matching using fuzzy c-means and artificial bee colony algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, matching, k-means, fuzzy-c-means

I have to cluster a list of jobs using fuzzy c-means optimized by the ABC Algorithm. any example of applying those algorithm together ??

thank you very much in advance for helping ...

Comment: @mjv, even though you edited.  This really doesn't make any sense lol.  Really badly asked!

Comment: @PaulM: agreed.  I don't have direct experience with ABC algorithm and I was wondering if someone would be able to make sense of this all before it gets closed...

Comment: Cleared up title a bit more, but also not sure on ABC algorithm and if it and c-means clustering get along.

Comment: I'm sorry , i edited the question , hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABC is used to optimize the FCM algorithm I'm working on a project in the same field and i found this helpful [FCM ABC](http://www.academicjournals.org/sre/PDF/pdf2010/18Jul/Karaboga%20and%20Ozturk.pdf)